# Published KMM android library won't sync with gradle

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a KMM library for my company's project, basically it contains network API calls and userSettings, I decided to do it by using KMM mobile library project. I had no problem building and publishing it to my private maven repo but now When I want to implement the library in my android project, It gives me this error:

`Failed to resolve: com.mycompany:myproject-android:0.0.1`

I use MyMavenRepo for publishing and I did exactly what it said on their docs!

Here is my library's gradle configuration:

```
kotlin {
    android {
        publishLibraryVariants("release")
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "${Config.Jvm.target}"
                useIR = true
            }
        }
    }
...
}


publishing {
    repositories.maven {
        name = "myMavenRepo"
        url = project.uri(Config.MyMavenRepo.url)
        credentials(PasswordCredentials::class)
    }
}
```

Here is my generated POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <!-- This module was also published with a richer model, Gradle metadata,  -->
  <!-- which should be used instead. Do not delete the following line which  -->
  <!-- is to indicate to Gradle or any Gradle module metadata file consumer  -->
  <!-- that they should prefer consuming it instead. -->
  <!-- do_not_remove: published-with-gradle-metadata -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject-android</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-android</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-okhttp</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>androidx.lifecycle</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.32</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.russhwolf</groupId>
      <artifactId>multiplatform-settings-no-arg-android</artifactId>
      <version>0.7.6</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.insert-koin</groupId>
      <artifactId>koin-core-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-core-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-auth-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-serialization-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
      <artifactId>ktor-client-logging-jvm</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-common</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.32</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-android-extensions-runtime</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.32</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Anyone knows what is the problem?

P.S: I use android studio canary 15 with AGP v7.0.0-alpha, gradle version: 7.0

Comment: Hello! This problem sounds similar to one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680387/can-only-add-kotlin-multiplatform-mobile-library-from-maven-by-using-releaseimpl). How are you setting the dependency on this library from Android project?

Comment: @ArtyomDegtyarev Hey! I solved this problem but now I'm facing another one, I commented more details on youtrack:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-10769